# Can't get UseEffect() to set State properly with spreader

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project in react using graphql. I have an object

`const [additionalInfo, setAdditionalInfo] = useEffect({})`,

which contains objects that have been selected. On this screen, I have data that is coming from my backend, which looks like: `{status: "single", work:"full-time", etc...}` that I need to add to my additionalInfo object if it contains a "!" (signifies that it was  previously selected). I've been trying to do this using a useEffect, but I'm having some issues.

```
useEffect(()=> {
   for (var item in  meDataData?.lifeStyle) {
     if ( meDataData?.lifeStyle[item]?.includes('!')) {
       setAdditionalInfo(
           ....additionalInfo,
           [item]: meDataData?.lifeStyle[item]?.substring(0,  
                   meDataData?.lifeStyle[item]?.length - 1)
       })
     }
   }
  }, [meDataData?.lifeStyle])
```

where `meDataData?.lifeStyle = {status: "single!", work:"full time!", dependents:"none", "higherEducation": null,}`only gives me `additionalInfo = {work:"full time"}`. After searching for solutions and answers for why the spreader wasn't working I tried:

```
 useEffect(()=> {
    for (var item in  meDataData?.lifeStyle) {
      if ( meDataData?.lifeStyle[item]?.includes('!')) {
        setAdditionalInfo(prevState =>{
          return ({
            ...prevState,
            [item]: meDataData?.lifeStyle[item]?.substring(0,  meDataData?.lifeStyle[item]?.length - 1)
          })
        })
      }
    }
   }, [meDataData?.lifeStyle])
```

which gave me `additionalInfo = {status:"single", higherEducation:undefined}`. Does anyone know why I am having this problem? I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new object and update it inside the loop before setting it into the state after the loop.

```js
const newInfo = {...additionalInfo};
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(meDataData?.lifeStyle ?? {})) 
    if (val?.includes('!'))
        newInfo[key] = val.slice(0, -1);
setAdditionalInfo(newInfo);
```